# A question about derivation in oblique view frustum

Tags: transformations, projections

Problem Description:

- Reference:
  [Oblique View Frustum Depth Projection and Clipping](http://www.terathon.com/lengyel/Lengyel-Oblique.pdf)

  "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics" 3rd edition, chapter 5.6.
- M is the original projection matrix.
- Plane C is the modified near plane, and C'=transpose(inverse(M))*C is the projected plane by M.
- Why in NDC the corner Q' of the view frustum lying opposite the plane C' is given by Q'=(Cx, Cy, 1, 1)?

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://community.khronos.org/t/oblique-frustum/49436/6)

quotations ：

“The points (+/-1, +/-1, 1, 1) are the four corners of the view frustum on the far plane in clip space.”

this should be the point Q' which equals (sgn(Cx), sgn(Cy), 1, 1)